# redirect from local host to phonegap

Tags: php, html, phonegap

I have and html page that is displayed on my phone. the user inputs some information and POST them to the php page on my localhost (WAMP). after the php page processes the data it should redirect the user to another page stored in phonegap! how to specify the address of this page?

in my php page I did this:

```
header("Location: blank.html");
```

in blank.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = 'file:///android_asset/destinationPage.php';
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason the browser stops at blank.html and just displays an empty page with no redirection. can you suggest any solutions for this?
the destination page is stored at C:\PhoneGapProject\www\destinationPage.php

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  window.location.replace = 'http://yourpathtofile';
```

By the way why this default.html with java script. Redirect the user from your Php code itself.

Comment: it's not working ... I just need to know how does the PHP server directs the phonegap application to open a specific page!

Comment: is the page "destinationPage.php" is accessible by web server. try to echo out something from the page and type the url "http://yourpath/destinationPage.php" in your browser and see the echo message.